# Why do we not get the same display of a particular font in web browser and java swing

Tags: java, swing, unicode, fonts

Suppose a font Kalpurush.ttf (you may find this font [here](http://assameseonline.com/css/kalpurush.ttf)). As it is an Assamese Font and may not have installed in everyone's computer, so, I've embedded this font in my website. It displays fine in any browser, (except android webview. I do not have any headache about android). In fact I've never found any Assamese font to be so nice.

Now I've tried this same font in a Java Swing Application. I've written this class:

```
public class AssameseFont {
public AssameseFont(){}

public Font Assamese(){
  File file = new File("kalpurush.ttf");
  Font as = null;
  try{          
   FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
   as = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, file);
   as = as.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 18);       
   GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().registerFont(as);

  }
  catch(FontFormatException | IOException e){
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ""+e);
  }
 return as;    
}    
}
```

I use to call this in my components using `setFont()` method.

But some of my texts does not display as it should be.
Why does it happen? Is it a font problem? Or am I doing anything wrong in my java code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As it is an Assamese Font and may not have installed in everyone's computer, so, I've embedded this font in my website. ..
>
> ```
> File file = new File("kalpurush.ttf");
> ```

That file will point to a (non-existent) file on the ***user's*** machine.

The font must instead be accessed by `URL`.

---

See also [Setting custom font](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13717481/418556).

[image]

---

The code seen on the linked thread, but with the `kalpurush.ttf` font.

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.URL;

class DisplayFont {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL fontUrl = new URL("http://assameseonline.com/css/kalpurush.ttf");
        Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, fontUrl.openStream());
        font = font.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN,20);
        GraphicsEnvironment ge =
            GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        ge.registerFont(font);

        JLabel l = new JLabel(
            "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. 0123456789");
        l.setFont(font);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, l);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is fine. but when I type `প্ৰাঞ্জল` in java it is displayed something like `পৰাঞ্জল` . It happens only in java. I do not know why.

Comment: @PranjalCholadhara If you are using MacOSX, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994815/rendering-devanagari-ligatures-unicode-in-java-swing-jcomponent-on-mac-os-x